# Error Xamarin Forms MediaPlugin

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Amigos tengo este problema de que no puedo usar la cámara con **Xamarin Forms**, tengo problemas con los perismos , me estoy guiando de esta referencia https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin/blob/master/README.md#android-file-provider-setup

y me pide crear una carpeta **xml**  en donde agrego el archivo **file_paths.xml** , pero cuando trato de correrlo y me mande el siguiente error

> Error       12: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'resource' with value '@xml/file_paths').   PhotoCam.Android    C:\Users\erpre\Source\Repos\PhotoCam\PhotoCam\PhotoCam.Android\obj\Debug\android\manifest\AndroidManifest.xml

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```js
private async void TmPic(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();
  if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported) {
    await DisplayAlert("Error", ":c Cámara no disponible.", "Continuar");
    return;
  } else {
    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(
      new StoreCameraMediaOptions {
        Directory = "Images",
          Name = DateTime.Now + "_img.jpg"
      });

    if (file == null) {
      return;
      myImg.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => file.GetStream());
    }

  }


}
```

file_paths.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
  <external-files-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" />
</paths>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.companyname.PhotoCam" android:installLocation="auto">
  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="12" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <application android:label="PhotoCam.Android" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
    <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="com.PhotoCam.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
      <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
    </provider>
  </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El error que te esta dando es porque Android no sabe que tiene el archivo file_paths bien porque no esta correcto o no esta correctamente añadido.

Lo primero, pincha con el boton derecho encima del fichero y selecciona propiedades, asegurate que la primera opcion (Build Action) es `AndroidResource` y en filename asegurate que esta bien file_paths.xml

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Despues asegurate que el contenido es algo así:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-files-path name="my_images" path="Pictures" />
    <external-files-path name="my_movies" path="Movies" />
</paths>
```

Sobretodo la primera y segunda linea.

En el archivo AndroidManifest.xml (que esta dentro de Properties en el proyecto de Android)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

debes tener algo así:

```
<application android:label="Nombre de la app" android:icon="@drawable/icon">
        <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" android:authorities="com.XXXX.YYYY.fileprovider" android:exported="false" android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS" android:resource="@xml/file_paths"></meta-data>
        </provider>
    </application>
```

com.XXXX.YYYY debe ser el nombre del apk que tipicamente es com.empresa.proyecto

Despues limpias la solución y recompilas.

Comment: oye creo tu respuesta me esta haciendo referencias Android studio y yo estoy usando xamarin forms ... lo único que no pude hacer fue encontrar esto
> (Build Action) es AndroidResource

Comment: Mi código esta copiado de una aplicación de Xamarin Forms hecha por mi y que esta publicada y funcionando. Si tienes visual studio en español los nombres estarán traducidos, si no es tal cual.

Comment: Cuando le doy a las propiedades de la carpeta xml solo me permite ver como propiedad su nombre ...  D:

Comment: Tienes que pedir las propiedades del fichero, no de la carpeta

Comment: Lo has conseguido? Si no te pongo pantallazos

Comment: pues me servirán mucho :3

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75985/discussion-between-mulflar-and-e-rawrdriguez-ophanim).

Comment: oye esta súper ya encuentra el xml pero me sigue saliendo esto >Plugin.Media.Abstractions.MediaPermissionException: Camera permission(s) are required.  Quizá se deba a esto pero no se que poner en empresa :S android:authorities="com.XXXX.YYYY.fileprovider"

Comment: Eso es algo completamente distinto, lo que pasa es que no has puesto los permisos de la cámara en el manifestaciones o que no le estas diciendo al usuario que te conceda permisos o las dos cosas